# Can't set css property on a button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a button to my website to change the number of columns displayed, because it's a dictionary and more columns would be more efficient with space, but perhaps more difficult to navigate. I'm just using straight HTML, PHP, CSS, and just this little bit of javascript, but when I click the button, nothing happens. I've tried what I can to fix it, but to no avail. Here's the script (with CSS)

```css
#col {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<center><button onclick="thrcol()">Three Columns</button></center>

<script type="text/javascript">
function thrcol() {
    document.getElementById("col").style.-webkit-column-count=3;
    document.getElementById("col").style.-moz-column-count=3;
    document.getElementById("col").style.column-count=3;
}
</script>


<div id="col"><!-- A bunch of boring PHP that works -->Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!</div>
```

I thought that this would just be simple, but, as I said, nothing happens. What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your error console?

Comment: Also... when access css attributes using javascript they are not accessed using their css names, but camelCase

Comment: What do you mean by `change the number of columns ?`

Comment: Try camel-casing the style attributes. Like `style.columnCount`. Edit: As El Guapo said earlier (sorry, didn't see his comment before adding mine)

Comment: Here's a fiddle that demonstrates the camelCase: http://jsfiddle.net/a10sffy9/ - I recommend closing this as it's just a typographical error in your code.

Comment: Oh, thanks, guys. I had no idea that was an issue. camelCase solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code was almost right, the only wrong thing was setting the style property. There are 2 ways to set a property to an object:

```
object.property = 'value';
object['property'] = 'value';
```

The first way `property` can contain only alphanumeric symbols and underscores. The second way you can use (almost) every symbol.

It is working now as expected:

```js
function thrcol() {
    document.getElementById("col").style.webkitColumnCount = 3;
    document.getElementById("col").style.mozColumnCount = 3;
    document.getElementById("col").style.columnCount = 3;
    // or:
    document.getElementById("col").style['-webkit-column-count'] = 3;
    document.getElementById("col").style['-moz-column-count'] = 3;
    document.getElementById("col").style['column-count'] = 3;
}
```

```css
button { display: block; }
#col {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="thrcol()">Three Columns</button>
<div id="col">
  Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!<br>Hello, World!
</div>
```

Another way to set such dash-containing css properties using javascript:

```
"margin-left" becomes "marginLeft"
"border-bottom" becomes "borderBottom"
"-webkit-column-count" becomes "webkitColumnCount"
```

Comment: `['-webkit-column-count']` won't work either. Dashes transform to camelCase, correct property is for example `webkitColumnCount`.

Comment: I tried the first way and it worked - what's wrong? I also checked the console - no messages.

Comment: The camelCase keys already exists, why add another key? And another benefit is accessing it as a property rather than string index can provide you with better autocomplete, if you editor knows how to handle the completion.

Comment: "Why add another key?" - What do you mean by that? I agree with @Al.G. here. Square bracket notation is another way of accessing a property of an object. There's nothing wrong with using `el.style['-webkit-column-count']`, since it'll refer to the same property as accessing `el.style.webkitColumnCount` (which you can verify - try applying `document.body.style['-webkit-filter'] = "blur(6px)"` in console and then typing `document.body.style.webkitFilter` and you'll see the value you assigned....)

Answer (score -1):

At first you must have document ready for setting event,then I think your css is not so correct.you can use this link.there are documentations and examples about html,css and javascript.
http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/javascript-events.html

Comment: This does nothing to do with the OP problem. They just declare a function - which does not require the DOM to be ready.